# Val is being updated

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this code below.

```
val newObject = oldObject.person //this is an open class realm object
newObject?.let{
   oldObject.person = null
}
```

`newObject` is now `null` after `oldObject.person` was reassigned. How can i avoid this? I need `newObject` to hold the initial value of `oldObject.person` before being updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `newObject` is pointing to the same reference than the `person` attribute

```
val newObject = oldObject.person.copy()
```

If you can't do that because `person` type does not allow copy (is not a data class by example) then you have make a new person and manually copy all the person atrributes

```
val neeObject = Person(
    attribute1 = oldObject.person.attribute1
    ...
)
```

Then you can update the `person` in the `oldObject`, because it wont be the same reference.